# unexpected result of Excel formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

i have the following formula; =BYROW(SEQUENCE(30;;0,01;0,01);LAMBDA(n;MOD(n;0,03)))=0.
Excel returns
{FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}

While I would expect
{FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}

Am i making a mistake somewhere? Please help (i have more array formulas returning unexpected results, i might use lambda wrong)
Best,

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in a locale where comma is the decimal point.

You cannot do exact comparisons with floating point numbers.  The numbers `0.01` and `0.03` cannot be represented exactly in binary, so what you get are very close approximations. The more arithmetic you do, the more you accumulate very small errors.

You should be doing your arithmetic as integers, and then divide the result by 100.

Comment: thx, that is it, the solution.